# can I see the owner/creator of a vcenter vm with pyvmomi

Tags: python, vsphere, vcenter, pyvmomi

The closest info I can find in the vSphere UI is the user of the "Clone completed" event in the events list in monitoring. Can i access this list with pyvmomi? Or any better alternative would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of information isn't part of the virtual machine object, so your best bet is to poll the events via `EventManager` Only caveat, if you have a particularly active environment, the events may rollover so using and polling a syslog would be the most consistent manner of obtaining that information.

Comment: thanks. Do you mean the syslog on the vm I am interested? is this info gets stored on the vm itself? Anyway not sure I have access to the machine.